# Validate remote logged in user credential in active directory

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, active-directory

I need to verify windows user (client in AD domain) from other computer (server in AD domain). Setup looks like this:

[Diagram of infrastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isudj.png)

- **Client App** is a product that client uses. It has an option to log in by custom authentication method using accounts in **MS SQL Database**. User also has an option of automatic log-in using its Windows account in **Active Directory** domain.
- **Server App** is used to authenticate **Client App** against product accounts (**MS SQL Database**) and domain accounts.
- **Active Directory server** creates domain for windows computers and contains User Group containing all accounts that are allowed to be authenticated by **Server App** if they are also linked to product account in **MS SQL database**.
- **MS SQL Database** contains custom product accounts. Every account can also be linked to **AD domain** account via username.

[Diagram of my idea of how this Active Directory authentication could work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNsa0.png)

My questions are:

1. How can I get and pass information about logged in windows account from client to server in C#? This information should be enough to fully check user credibility. I can't ask client user for either windows domain account password or product account password.
2. Is this *proper way* of achieving this kind of authentication or I should research something else? If something else, then what?

Comment: What kind of server app, and what technology/framework? For example, IIS will take care of Windows authentication for you.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Server is just regular Windows .NET console application.

Comment: How are you doing the server/client communication?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Windows Communication Foundation

Comment: I don't have any experience there. But I did find this, maybe it will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-multiple-authentication-schemes-with-wcf